# Sed Command not working?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a table like this in a unix file. Plain txt. I want to replace the ID columns numbers with values such as 9 = cat, 22 = dog. When I use the command

sed 's/9/cat/'

It is replacing all instants of 9 with cat. I can't just make it for that line only because sometimes the id would match the numbers in the values. Thank in advance.

```
Original Table 
    MAX(VALUE)  Id
     37787           9
    151326          22
    108339          24
     10069         303
```

Expect Result Table

```
MAX(VALUE)  Id
 37787          9 
151326          22
108339          24
 10069          303
```

What I am getting

```
 MAX(VALUE)  Id
 37787          9 
151326          22
10833Cat        24
 1006Cat        303
```

2nd question

```
sed 's/22/cat/' Report >> Report
sed 's/24/dog/' Report >> Report
sed 's/801/lion/' Report >> Report
sed 's/821/lion/' Report >> Report
```

When I use this command it seems to print out 4 tables of the same results. I tried using > but then no table shows up. any1 knows why ? thanks again .

Answer (score 3):

To replace a number at the end of a line, include the end-of-line anchor:

```
sed 's/9$/Cat/'
```

To prevent replacing 9 by Cat in 19 which should go to Fish, progress from the longest Id numbers to the shortest ones.

Also, instead of invoking `sed` many times, invoke it once with several commands (some syntax is not universally supported in all versions of sed):

```
sed 's/22$/Dog/;s/9$/Cat/'
```

or

```
sed -e 's/22$/Dog/' -e 's/9$/Cat/'
```

To change a file in place, use `-i`:

```
sed -i~ 's/...//' Report
```

(if your version of sed supports it). Writing to a file you are reading at the same time doesn't work.